# How to share certificates between Firefox and Okular on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, certificate, digital-signature, okular

I made a fresh installation of **Ubuntu 22.04** and successfully imported the personal certificate into Firefox. If my memory serves me well, Okular accessed Firefox's NSS database with certificates located in a shared folder ([docs](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/okular/okular/signatures.html)). Since they are both served as Ubuntu snaps, they can no longer share certificates database. Okular's backend config does not provide any way to import them except by providing a path.

Is there a way to somehow copy the certificate from `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/<some-id>.default/???` to something like `~/snap/okular/common/.pki/nssdb`? Is there a better way?

Comment: The Okular manual says that it will check Firefox -- Somehow I doubt that it can cope with `snap` to do that.  You could set-up a `symlink` to the _burried_ firefoc store (_maybe_ ???).  Maybe there's something deeper int he Okular documentation that can help.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had the same problem (i.e. Firefox and Okular being both a "snap" and so probably unable to share files with each other), and I managed to solve it by copying some files from Thunderbird's profile folder. I copied the following files from the `~/.thunderbird/XXXXXXXX.default-release/` folder into `~/cert/okular`: `cert9.db`, `encrypted-openpgp-passphrase.txt`, `key4.db`, `pkcs11.txt`. I then imported this folder in the `Settings -> Configure backends -> PDF` menu in okular and after the restart I could see the certificates and digitally sign.

I have not properly tested if the 4 files are all needed or just one of them, I just copied them based on the fact that their name was suggestive enough :)